# JavaScript: multiple instances wrong reference to private property

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, private-members, private-methods

In the fiddle is a "class" I have written to manage navigation over the data model and a test which shows that multiple instances (starting from second) of this "class" are referencing something wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/btvmnaxc/
(outputs to console)

Expected output would be

```
[{"name":"xx"}]
[{"name":"yy"}]
```

But after setting Elements via setElements, in other methods Elements is empty, strangely only after creating the second instance. I could think that setElements overwrites the reference, but why other methods keep this old reference instead of getting a new one from the var.

Could somebody explain this behavior?

P.S. I probably can think on a solution, as packing vars in a property which is an object.

```
function Pagination() {
  var props = {Elements:[], ...}
}
```

P.S.S

```
function Pagination() {
  var that = this;
  var Elements = [0,1];
  var Frame = [];
  var FrameNumber = 0;
  var EntitiesPerFrame = 25;
  var FrameChangedCB = [];

  this.subscribeFrameChange = function(cb) {
    if (typeof cb === "function") {
      FrameChangedCB.push(cb);
    } else {
      throw new Error("Not a function");
    }
  }

  this.setEntitiesPerFrame = function(entities_per_frame) {
    entities_per_frame = parseInt(entities_per_frame);
    if (entities_per_frame > 0) {
      EntitiesPerFrame = entities_per_frame;
      while (!this.canDisplayFrame(FrameNumber) && FrameNumber > 0) {
        FrameNumber--;
      }
      calculateFrame();
    }
  }

  frameChanged = function() {
    FrameChangedCB.forEach(function(cb) {
      cb();
    });
  }

  this.setElements = function(elements) {
    if (Array.isArray(elements)) {
      Elements = elements;
      calculateFrame();
      console.log("qq");
    } else {
      throw new Error("Can only work with arrays");
    }
  }

  this.getStart = function() {
    return FrameNumber * EntitiesPerFrame;
  }

  this.getEnd = function() {
    var end = (FrameNumber + 1) * EntitiesPerFrame;
    return end > Elements.length ? Elements.length : end;
  }

  this.getEntitiesPerFrame = function() {
    return EntitiesPerFrame;
  }

  calculateFrame = function() {
    var start = that.getStart();
    var end = that.getEnd();
    if (that.canDisplayFrame(FrameNumber)) {
      Frame = Elements.slice(
        start,
        end
      );
      frameChanged();
    } else {
      throw new Error("Boundaries");
    }
  }

  this.canDisplayFrame = function(nr) {
    nr = parseInt(nr);
    var can = false;
    var start = nr * EntitiesPerFrame
    var end = (nr + 1) * EntitiesPerFrame;

    if (start <= Elements.length && nr >= 0) {
      can = true;
    }

    return can;
  }

  this.getFrame = function() {
    return Frame;
  }

  this.next = function() {
    return this.goto(FrameNumber + 1);
  }

  this.prev = function() {
    return this.goto(FrameNumber - 1);
  }

  this.goto = function(frame_nr) {
    var changed = false;
    if (that.canDisplayFrame(frame_nr)) {
      FrameNumber = parseInt(frame_nr);
      calculateFrame();
      changed = true;
    }
    return changed;
  }

  this.getLength = function() {
    return Elements.length;
  }


}


var b = new Pagination();
var a = new Pagination();
a.setElements([{name: 'xx'}]);
b.setElements([{name: 'yy'}]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a.getFrame()));
console.log(JSON.stringify(b.getFrame()));
```

Comment: Please post the complete code in the question (you can still [edit] it), not (only) in an external fiddle.

Comment: Your `frameChanged` and `calculateFrame` functions are [accidentally global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are abusing [implicit globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Your `Pagination` function contains two places where a function is assigned to an identifier without using `var`:

```
  calculateFrame = function() {
    var start = that.getStart();
    var end = that.getEnd();
    if (that.canDisplayFrame(FrameNumber)) {
      Frame = Elements.slice(
        start,
        end
      );
      frameChanged();
    } else {
      throw new Error("Boundaries");
    }
  }
```

This will assign this function to a global variable named `calculateFrame` and any call to `calculateFrame()` will be calling whichever of those was assigned last (and therefore be using whatever scope it has access to).

To fix this, use `var`:

```
  var calculateFrame = function() {
    var start = that.getStart();
    var end = that.getEnd();
    if (that.canDisplayFrame(FrameNumber)) {
      Frame = Elements.slice(
        start,
        end
      );
      frameChanged();
    } else {
      throw new Error("Boundaries");
    }
  }
```

Or better yet, use a named function declaration:

```
  function calculateFrame() {
    var start = that.getStart();
    var end = that.getEnd();
    if (that.canDisplayFrame(FrameNumber)) {
      Frame = Elements.slice(
        start,
        end
      );
      frameChanged();
    } else {
      throw new Error("Boundaries");
    }
  }
```

After fixing the two places where you have this issue, the snippet outputs the expected result.

```js
function Pagination() {
  var that = this;
  var Elements = [0, 1];
  var Frame = [];
  var FrameNumber = 0;
  var EntitiesPerFrame = 25;
  var FrameChangedCB = [];

  this.subscribeFrameChange = function(cb) {
    if (typeof cb === "function") {
      FrameChangedCB.push(cb);
    } else {
      throw new Error("Not a function");
    }
  }

  this.setEntitiesPerFrame = function(entities_per_frame) {
    entities_per_frame = parseInt(entities_per_frame);
    if (entities_per_frame > 0) {
      EntitiesPerFrame = entities_per_frame;
      while (!this.canDisplayFrame(FrameNumber) && FrameNumber > 0) {
        FrameNumber--;
      }
      calculateFrame();
    }
  }

  function frameChanged() {
    FrameChangedCB.forEach(function(cb) {
      cb();
    });
  }

  this.setElements = function(elements) {
    if (Array.isArray(elements)) {
      Elements = elements;
      calculateFrame();
      console.log("qq");
    } else {
      throw new Error("Can only work with arrays");
    }
  }

  this.getStart = function() {
    return FrameNumber * EntitiesPerFrame;
  }

  this.getEnd = function() {
    var end = (FrameNumber + 1) * EntitiesPerFrame;
    return end > Elements.length ? Elements.length : end;
  }

  this.getEntitiesPerFrame = function() {
    return EntitiesPerFrame;
  }

  function calculateFrame() {
    var start = that.getStart();
    var end = that.getEnd();
    if (that.canDisplayFrame(FrameNumber)) {
      Frame = Elements.slice(
        start,
        end
      );
      frameChanged();
    } else {
      throw new Error("Boundaries");
    }
  }

  this.canDisplayFrame = function(nr) {
    nr = parseInt(nr);
    var can = false;
    var start = nr * EntitiesPerFrame
    var end = (nr + 1) * EntitiesPerFrame;

    if (start <= Elements.length && nr >= 0) {
      can = true;
    }

    return can;
  }

  this.getFrame = function() {
    return Frame;
  }

  this.next = function() {
    return this.goto(FrameNumber + 1);
  }

  this.prev = function() {
    return this.goto(FrameNumber - 1);
  }

  this.goto = function(frame_nr) {
    var changed = false;
    if (that.canDisplayFrame(frame_nr)) {
      FrameNumber = parseInt(frame_nr);
      calculateFrame();
      changed = true;
    }
    return changed;
  }

  this.getLength = function() {
    return Elements.length;
  }


}


var b = new Pagination();
var a = new Pagination();
a.setElements([{
  name: 'xx'
}]);
b.setElements([{
  name: 'yy'
}]);
console.log(a.getFrame());
console.log(b.getFrame());
```

Comment: Abusing? I don't think this was intentional :-)

Comment: @Bergi Unintentional abuse is still abuse in my book. ;)

Comment: It was not intentional indeed. Anyway I appreciate your help guys.

Comment: @IgorFialko Remember to run your code in strict mode. Among other things, it will prevent you from using implicit globals.

Comment: I usualy do. But the project from which the snippet is originating has to support IE9 and also has no transpilers, so sometimes these errors appear unfortunately.

Comment: We plan though to move to babel, typescript etc. to minimize errors of this kind.

Comment: @IgorFialko Your first comment there makes no sense. Strict mode code can run in IE9 just fine. No transpiler needed.

Comment: @JLRishe Hm, support for use strict is firstly introduced in IE11 as far as I understand.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp
http://caniuse.com/#feat=use-strict
P.S. What I see though after a small research, is that the statement should cause no problems in lower versions. Thanks.